# Работа с RemoteObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Два вопроса по работе RemoteObjectManager:

1. Как регулировать отправку запроса за данными? Возможно сделать POST-запрос вместо GET? Динамически формировать параметры запроса?
2. При изменении масштаба, карта пытается отобразить заново только разницу, выбирая по id объектов? Т.е. на клиенте данные не удаляются с карты вместе с новым запросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас нет возможности регулировать отправку запроса за данными. Старые данные сейчас удаляются после того, как подгружаются новые данные. Теоретически на разных зумах может быть виден один и тот же объект, вот чтобы он не промаргивал при смене зума, была сделана такая логика обработки.

Comment: Спасибо! Ещё уточняющий вопрос: объекты в RemoteObjectManager должны передаваться с уникальным id. id должен быть уникальный даже в рамках разных сущностей (например, кластеров и меток). При этом id должен быть одинаков для разных запросов (т.к. по нему вычисляется разница). И id должен иметь тип "number" (число, предположительно integer). Если всё верно, тогда остаётся очень мало возможностей для формирования уникального id при наличии разных сущностей.

Comment: id может быть строкой

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодиться. Для динамического формирования параметров запроса выход оказался максимально простой:

```
remoteObjectManager.setUrlTemplate("/path.json?zoom=%z&"+$.param(getAjaxData()));
remoteObjectManager.reloadData();
```

В данном случае remoteObjectManager - это переменная, куда сохранили менеджер при создании. 
getAjaxData - функция собирает данные для отправки и возвращает объект.