# Yandex Maps API RemoteObjectManager custom server url

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835952/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-remoteobjectmanager), мб что-то поменялось:

Можно ли как-то добавлять кастомные параметры при загрузке объектов с сервера с помощью [RemoteObjectManager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/RemoteObjectManager.html#RemoteObjectManager__param-urlTemplate)?

Условно чтобы вместо `urlTemplate` была callback функция в которой можно было бы сформировать `url` для обращения к серверу.

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/frontend.html#manager-creating) API Яндекс.Карт есть примеры формирования адресов колбеков